# Rewrite rails model method to ActiveRecord request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

`User has_many microposts`  `Micropost belongs to users`

take users who have more than 10 microposts

Controller:

```
def active_users
  @users  = User.active_users
end
```

Model

```
def self.active_users
  self.select { |u| u.microposts.size > 10}
end
```

how to rewrite  method `active_users` to ActiveRecord request (probably  with using `:count` `:group` methods)

```
                             **UPDATE**
```

`the solution`

`self.joins(:microposts).group("users.id").having("count(*) > 10").all`

Comment: yep answer is below `**UPDATE**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter_Cache is your answer.

Go for this maybe:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache

`User has_many microposts`

```
Micropost 
  belongs to users
  counter_cache: true
```

Then do a migration:

```
class AddMicropostCountToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :microposts_count, :integer
  end
end
```

Then you can go for something like.

```
@users  = User.where('microposts_count > ?', 10)
```

For further customization, check the links.

Comment: see my questin under update message, i'll solve my problem using AR